# VPN-like shared Cloud Storage options?

Tags: cloud, storage, vpn, cloud-storage

I work for an NPO, and we opened an office across the country.  Our local server-based VPN where we store our shared user data, has thus become slow to access and use for our far-away employees.

I'm looking into a full Cloud based alternative to this, that works as much like regular VPN storage as possible.

In that it:

- Has individual logins, but grants access to same file storage area.
- Has a desktop application that allows drag-and-drop
- Is secure

Notes:

- I'm not a fan of DropBox after seeing it's sync bug out and max out peoples hard drives at a previous employer.

Thank you!

Kind Regards,
- Mikhail

Answer (score -1):

If you want my honest recommendation, look into the [NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/) application combined with FTP. This is of course assuming that your clients use Windows. I have this running across 4 windows clients with a single PC hosting everything. It's not sync, it's remote storage, so once everything's uploaded, the drive's cache gets deleted. And, the FTP server gets mounted as a regular Windows hard disk.